# Calling SharePoint Rest API with access token using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, access-token, office365api, sharepoint-online

I have got access token after login to Office 365 which is returned to my HTML page. Now i want to call share-point REST APi to get list items, read Documents etc. 
I am writing ajax call for that and passing access token in authorization header with Bearer.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mtsite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('test')/items",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer my-access-token",              
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"              
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

But it is saying `UnauthorizedAccessException (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized))`

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Yes, because the call is returning result with success in rest client